# Why is my code not displaying my image when I run the program on pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm using Pygame which I've imported onto Pycharm.

For my code, I'm trying to display an image from my files to load onto my program when I run it but it doesn't work. The image is in the same file as my python code. When I run it all I see is a black screen.

The file pathway to the image is correct as it showed me a preview of the image when I hovered over the png file.

Here is my code:

```python
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1275, 775))

bg_surface = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/DavinaXXX/Documents/Python/Testing/Background.png")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame = quit()
            sys.exit()

screen.blit(bg_surface, (0, 0))
```

Comment: You should write in `while` loop and did you try relative path?

Comment: Please read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Please read [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Do not post screenshots of the code. Paste the code.

Comment: You've to call  `screen.blit(...)` **in** the `while`-loop rather than **after** the loop. Furthermore you've to update the display with `pygame.display.flip()` (in the loop)

Answer (score 0):

Did you get this to work?

After changes are made to the screen, they all get written or "flushed" to the display (from a queue of updates) when the `pygame.display.flip()` or `pygame.display.update()` is called.  You do not have this call, so the blit changes cannot be seen in the window.

There's also a problem with the `pygame.quit()`, and the `blit()` needed to be indented to be inside the `while` loop, but probably this was just a paste-problem when writing the question.

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1275, 775))

bg_surface = pygame.image.load("C:/Users/DavinaXXX/Documents/Python/Testing/Background.png")

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()                   # <<-- HERE (repair)
            sys.exit()


    screen.blit(bg_surface, (0, 0))         # <<-- HERE (indent into while)
    pygame.display.flip()                   # <<-- AND HERE (added)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I manged to get this code working.